# What to replace the DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl class?

Tags: java, hibernate, jdbc, migration

In the project I work with Hibernate ORM version 4.2.6.Final previously was used. Now I'm trying to update it to the latest release, which is 4.3.10.Final. However, `org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl` is no longer mentioned [in the docs](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/javadocs/org/hibernate/service/jdbc/connections/internal/package-summary.html) and no longer supplied.

This is how this class is used in the code I work with:

```
( (DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl) ( 
    (SessionFactoryImpl) getDAO().getSessionFactory() )
        .getConnectionProvider() )
            .setDataSource(ds);
```

What can it be replaced with? And where can I find the mention of its removal in the Hibernate docs or release notes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, by [using GrepCode.com](http://grepcode.com/search?query=DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl) multi-repository search engine I figured out that `DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl` class was not actually removed. Instead, since Hibernate 4.3.0, some classes are moved:

from `org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal`

to `org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal`.

So import statement has to be changed to

```
import org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl;
```